# Can't get_to vector of object inside itself with Nlohmann's JSON

Tags: c++, type-conversion, nlohmann-json

I've got the following code (simplified):

```cpp
namespace nlohmann {
// https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/1749#issuecomment-772996219
template <class T>
void to_json(nlohmann::json &j, const std::optional<T> &v) {
    if (v.has_value())
        j = *v;
    else
        j = nullptr;
}

template <class T>
void from_json(const nlohmann::json &j, std::optional<T> &v) {
    if (j.is_null())
        v = std::nullopt;
    else
        v = j.get<T>(); /* ERROR LOCATION */
}
} // namespace nlohmann

namespace discordpp{
class Component {
  public:
    Component(const std::optional<std::vector<Component>> &components)
        : components(components) {}

    std::optional<std::vector<Component>> components;

    // (Resolved) NLOHMANN_DEFINE_TYPE_INTRUSIVE(Component, components)
    friend void to_json(nlohmann::json &nlohmann_json_j,
                        const Component &nlohmann_json_t) {
        nlohmann_json_j["components"] = nlohmann_json_t.components;
    }
    friend void from_json(const nlohmann::json &nlohmann_json_j,
                          Component &nlohmann_json_t) {
        nlohmann_json_j.at("components").get_to(nlohmann_json_t.components); /* ERROR LOCATION */
    }
};
}// namespace discordpp
```

Compiling returns the error `error: no matching function for call to ‘nlohmann::basic_json<>::get<std::vector<discordpp::Component, std::allocator<discordpp::Component> > >() const’`
Is there maybe something I could predeclare to solve this?

Tried setting up an adl_serializer like this, same issue

```cpp
namespace nlohmann {
template<> struct adl_serializer<discordpp::Component> {
    static void to_json(json &nlohmann_json_j, const discordpp::Component &nlohmann_json_t) {
        NLOHMANN_JSON_EXPAND(NLOHMANN_JSON_PASTE(
            NLOHMANN_JSON_TO, type, custom_id, disabled, style, label, emoji,
            url, options, placeholder, min_values, max_values, components))
    }

    static void from_json(const json &nlohmann_json_j, discordpp::Component &nlohmann_json_t) {
        NLOHMANN_JSON_EXPAND(NLOHMANN_JSON_PASTE(
            NLOHMANN_JSON_FROM, type, custom_id, disabled, style, label, emoji,
            url, options, placeholder, min_values, max_values, components))
    }
};
} // namespace nlohmann
```

I changed it to a vector of shared pointers and now I get `error: no matching function for call to ‘nlohmann::basic_json<>::get<discordpp::Component>() const’` in the `adl_serializer` I wrote to handle it

```cpp
template <typename T> struct adl_serializer<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>> {
    static void to_json(json &j, const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> &v) {
        j = json::array();
        for (auto t : v) {
            j.push_back(*t);
        }
    }

    static void from_json(const json &j, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> &v) {
        if (!j.is_array()) {
            throw json::type_error::create(317, "j must be an array", j);
        }
        for (auto t : j) {
            v.push_back(std::make_shared<T>(j.get<T>())); /* Error is here */
        }
    }
};
```

Mirrored at https://github.com/nlohmann/json/discussions/3047

Edit:

Full source (do a recursive clone): https://github.com/DiscordPP/echo-bot/tree/dev-objects

Failed build: https://github.com/DiscordPP/echo-bot/runs/3799394029?check_suite_focus=true

Edit 2: It's fine when I do `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Component>> components;`, it just doesn't seem to be able handle 2 third party parsers, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing some thinking on @Niels's answer and I realized that `friend void from_json` is taking an already-constructed `Component&` but `Component` doesn't have a default constructor. I added `Component() : components(std::nullopt) {}` and we're off to the races!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you try to have a member with type `std::optional<std::vector<Component>>` in class `Component`, and `std::optional` does not work with incomplete types. Replacing this with `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<Component>>` should work.

Comment: That's spitting out `error: no matching function for call to ‘nlohmann::basic_json<>::get_to(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Component> >&) const’` when I try to implement it

I also need some way to indicate that the field isn't present instead of just `null` or the DIscord API will send me errors. I did just now realize that using an `adl_serializer` at all may not work for that, hmm.

Comment: Yeah maybe I was being optimistic by using the built-in macros, because I have some fields that need to be omittable, some that need to be nullable, and some that need to be both.

Comment: (Of course, additional code is needed to work with smart pointers. But the core should be the incomplete type. This is also the reason why we can't have `std::unordered_map<string, json>` inside class `json`.

Comment: It seems like in that case that it wouldn't compile even if I excluded `nlohmann_json_j.at("components").get_to(nlohmann_json_t.components);` but it does

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are calling `get_to` on a vector of `Component`, but you cannot convert `json` into `Component`.

A solution would be to add a constructor:

```
explicit Component(const nlohmann::json &nlohmann_json_j = nlohmann::json()) 
{
    // do whatever you have to do
}
```

Note that I added `= nlohmann::json()` because `std::vector<Component>` needs the default constructor.

Note: I tested this approach and it works as expected.

Live demo:

https://replit.com/@ichramm/somerandomtest

Compile with:

```
clang++-7 -Iinclude -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp && ./main
```

---

**Update:** I am adding more details because it looks that the issue is not fully understood.

The problem **has nothing to do** with `std::optional`.

The problem is that there is a **vector of Component** with it is supposed to be created from a **vector of json**.

You provided no way read/write optionals from/to the json, but you didn't provide a way to read/write objects of type `Component`.

In the line `j.get<T>();`, `T` is `std::vector<Component>`, and `j` can be thought as `std::vector<Json>`.

Alternatively, you could create a function `from_json` for your type `Component`. I haven't tested it but it looks like it may work.

Comment: From my understanding this was the conversion that `from_json` is supposed to & is normally able to provide, I guess the detection just breaks when you try to do it like this.

Comment: You are right, but also wrong. I will extend my answer with more details.

Comment: The error saying that there's no `from_json` for `Component` is coming from the `from_json` for `Component` though, that's where I'm confused.

Comment: In this case I am inclined to favor nlohmann's answer, on which he states that the member variable has incomplete type.